# C#: New line and tab characters in strings

Tags: c#

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("Line 1");
//insert new line character
//insert tab character
sb.Append("Line 2");
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("example.txt"))
{
    sq.Write(sb.ToString());
}
```

How can insert a new line and tab character in this example?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("Line 1");
sb.Append(System.Environment.NewLine); //Change line
sb.Append("\t"); //Add tabulation
sb.Append("Line 2");
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("example.txt"))
{
    sw.Write(sb.ToString());
}
```

You can find detailed [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) on TAB (and other escape character here).

Comment: Instead of `sb.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);` one can use `sb.AppendLine();`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You are right, many way is possible to do the same task. Good job on this one.

Comment: Is this platform independent ? for example, Environment.Newline is platform independent while "\n" is not.

Answer (score 16):

Use:

```
sb.AppendLine();
sb.Append("\t");
```

for better portability. **[`Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx)** may not necessarily be `\n`; Windows uses `\r\n`, for example.

Comment: Actually, Windows uses `\r\n` (carriage return + linefeed).

Comment: Whoops. Thanks Joshua; fixed.

Comment: Is this platform independent ? for example, Environment.Newline is platform independent while "\n" is not.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on if you mean '\n' (linefeed) or '\r\n' (carriage return + linefeed). The former is not the Windows default and will not show properly in some text editors (like Notepad).

You can do

```
sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
sb.Append("\t");
```

or

```
sb.Append("\r\n\t");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sb.Append(Environment.Newline);
sb.Append("\t");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sb.AppendLine();
```

or

```
sb.Append( "\n" );
```

And

```
sb.Append( "\t" );
```

Comment: And the most important one is missing. `System.Environment.NewLine` is a **must-know** after you leave this page.

Answer (score 0):

```
    StringBuilder SqlScript = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var file in lstScripts)
    {
        var input = File.ReadAllText(file.FilePath);
        SqlScript.AppendFormat(input, Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

http://afzal-gujrat.blogspot.com/