# Enter Key code in MessageBox object (Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

Enter in MessageBox:

My Message:
Warning:
Do you want to continue?

Code:
MessageBox.Show("Warning: {ENTER(?)} Do you want to continue?");

Rather than the {ENTER(?)} to send enter code and message divide to two line.

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
MessageBox.Show("Warning:\nDo you want to continue?");
```

`\n` stands for NewLine. You can use `Environment.NewLine`, too. Please check out this Question 
[C#: New line and tab characters in strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157520/c-new-line-and-tab-characters-in-strings) 
it might contain other helpful answers.